# SweetAlert not working with single quotes

Tags: javascript, html, popup

When using SweetAlert i'm having problems when using single quotes for example the code below works

```
<script>

function test()
{

Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  }
})


}

</script>
```

But when using this with single quotes (within php echo) - it will not work

**text: "You won't be able to revert this!"**, = ok

**text: 'You won't be able to revert this!'**, = not ok.

is there a answer to this puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unescaped quote in the word `won't`. If you wish to use single quotes to define your string, you should escape it, like so: `'You won\'t be able to revert this!'`

Comment: Can't believe it. Been looking at that code for days.  Thanks